# Foreach function for Class

Tags: c#, class, foreach

I have created the following class:

```
public class LocationTreeAlsTree
{
    public ComponentRef PartsOfTree { get; set; }
    public class ComponentRef
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<ComponentRef> Children { get; set; }
    }

    static List<ComponentRef> LoadUnits(IEnumerable<XElement> 
    _componentenRef)
    {
         return _componentenRef.Select(x => new ComponentRef()
         {
              ID = x.Attribute("ref").Value,
              Children = LoadUnits(x.Elements("componentRef"))
         }).ToList();
    }

    public LocationTreeAlsTree(string _filename)
    {
         // Dateiname des LocationTree-Files
         string locationtreeFile = _filename;

         // Neuer Streamreader um Encoding UTF16 Fehler zu umgehen
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(locationtreeFile, Encoding.UTF8);
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

         // Generiere eine Tree-Struktur vom Location Tree
         List<ComponentRef> units = LoadUnits(doc.Descendants("componentRef"));
         //ComponentRef Tree = new ComponentRef();
         PartsOfTree = units.First();
         units = null;
    }
}
```

I have tried to inplement foreach function to this class. I have no idea how to implement IEnumerable to this class. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Implement foreach to do what?

Comment: for an normal foreach cyle in c# foreach ()

Comment: I mean what foreach will loop?

Comment: outside the class, i don´t understand your question. My class is not able to be used by foreach, and i am trying to get this function integrated, that´s all.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use an instance of your class in a foreach loop? Implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @Sweeper I think he is looking for indexer

Comment: What are the elements that should be iterated over, in other words the elements the foreach loop will enumerate? Your question and problem description is entirely unclear. We cannot look into your mind. You will have to **clearly and unambiguously** communicate to us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry for that, but for me it´s absolutely clear. I want to use foreach for an instance of my class to get all the elements... i can´t understand why you define my question as unclear...

Comment: "_but for me it´s absolutely clear_" Yeah, you really believe we can read your mind. What are the elements. Be concrete and clear! Mind you, we don't have the problem you are trying to not tell us concrete details about, so if this problem gets not solved it is not to our disadvantage. If you refuse to clearly communicate, well, ... It's in your own hands to make it easy or difficult for us to help you...

Comment: let me try to explain. my class has id and childrens. it is a tree structure based on named elements from an xml-file. Every single element inside of the xml-file has the same name. the difference for each element is the id-number. Inside of each id-number are a lot of different information stored. I must generate a treeview inside my wpf. i have created this class and now i am trying to get it working with wpf. But for my solution i must able to walk trough the tree by foreach function. i am a beginner in c# and wpf. for me it ist difficult to explain my demands... sorry for that...

Comment: Is the List<ComponentRef> returned by the LoadUnits method the list you want to iterate over with `foreach` then?

Comment: By the way, if your problem is about how to display your  LocationTreeAlsTree data in a WPF TreeView, you would have asked the completely wrong question. ;-)

Comment: Ok... so teach me... but i want to have this possibility implemented....

Comment: For a TreeView in WPF you would only need a tree-like, or nested collection of some items that themselves could/would have collections of (child) items. Basically, your `ComponentRef` class would have this capability (it has a List<ComponentRef> of child ComponentRef instances, or so it looks to me). Just make ComponentRef a non-nested class, and use a collection of top-level ComponentRef items as ItemsSource for your TreeView. No need enumerating those items and trying to add them one-by-one manually to the TreeView. ;-)

Comment: Also create an [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate) for your TreeView that properly presents the data of each ComponentRef item and also specifies the ComponentRef property that provides the child items. (The HierarchicalDataTemplate is crucial for the TreeView to know where/how it should get possible child items from a ComponentRef object.) If you have done that, that's it. That's all that is required to make a TreeView work. Little to no additional code in C# necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Imagining that you want to loop through the list of `SomeClass` you can inherit from IEnumerable

```
public class LocationTreeAlsTree : IEnumerable<SomeClass>
{    
     public List<SomeClass> Something; // that is filled somewhere in class

     public IEnumerator<SomeClass> GetEnumerator()
     {
          return Something.GetEnumerator();
     }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
          return GetEnumerator();
     }
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
LocationTreeAlsTree tree = new LocationTreeAlsTree();
foreach(var t in tree)
{
    // do something
}
```